# How to get text from a <div> with a 'style' attribute?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I would like to get the address information for the school from this [link](http://www.geteducated.com/profiles/show/online-degrees/stephen-f-austin-state-university/perkins-college-of-education-undergraduate/395/5401/undergraduate-certificate-in-hospitality-administration). The HTML I'm interested in looks like this:

```
<div style="float:left;width:100%;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:30px;">
  <div>1936 North St.</div>
  <div>Natchitoches, TX 75962</div>
  <div>936-468-2901</div>
</div>
```

The desired text would be:

```
1936 North St.
Natchitoches, TX 75962
936-468-2901
```

Here is what I attempted:

```
address = soup.find('div', 'float:left;width:100%;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:30px;')
print address
```

My output: `None`

I thought that `soup.find()` took an attribute as an argument, and that 'style' was an attribute, so passing the name of the attribute would get me the contents ...

Any suggestions or a BeautifulSoup implementation for how I would get the address text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get exactly what you want:

```
address = soup.find('div', {'style':'float:left;width:100%;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:30px;'})
print address.get_text()
```

use a dict to define the `style` attr

use `get_text()` to get text between tags

Comment: Thx Christian, just wondering: why you need to define the 'style' attr as a dict?

Comment: So that it creates a dict telling the parser to get the `div` tag but only the ones where `style` = `'float:left;width:100%;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:30px;'`

Comment: but you dont have to use a class you can do
`('div', style='float:left;width:100%;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:30px;')`

Answer (score 1):

In order to search by an attribute, you need to tell BeautifulSoup which attribute to look at. There are a couple of ways to do this:

```
>>> soup.find('div', style='float:left;width:100%;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:30px;')
<div style="float:left;width:100%;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:30px;">
<div>1936 North St.</div>
<div>Natchitoches, TX 75962</div>
<div>936-468-2901</div>
</div>
```

```
>>> soup.find('div', {
...     'style': 'float:left;width:100%;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:30px;'
... })
<div style="float:left;width:100%;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:30px;">
<div>1936 North St.</div>
<div>Natchitoches, TX 75962</div>
<div>936-468-2901</div>
</div>
```

The latter is particularly useful if you're searching on the `class` attribute, which can't be a keyword argument because it's a reserved word in Python.